# How do I declare a TDictionary enumerator?

Tags: delphi, generics, dictionary, delphi-2009

I've got a TDictionary that stores a bunch of objects indexed by name, and I'd like to be able to examine all of the objects.  So I tried this:

```
var enumerator: TMyObject;
begin
   for enumerator in myDictionary do
```

But that wouldn't compile. "Incompatible types: 'TMyObject' and 'TPair'

So I tried it a bit differently:

```
var enumerator: TPair<string, TMyObject>;
```

That didn't compile either.  This error message is even stranger: Incompatible types: 'TPair' and 'TPair'

So apparently I need some sort of funky grammar to enumerate my dictionary with a **for .. in** loop.  Anyone know how to declare it properly?

EDIT: Fabio Gomes gave an example that works properly, but my code still doesn't compile using his method.  Maybe it's because I'm working in a different unit?  The dictionary and the class it's using for the Value side are both defined in one unit, and this code is elsewhere. Does that make it a bug in the compiler? Can anyone verify this?

EDIT 2: Found the problem.  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=69461 if anyone's interested.

Comment: is this question really off-topic?

Comment: @mjn: I closed it that way because there was no "turns out my code is fine; it's a compiler error" close reason.

Answer (score 7):

This works just as expected:

```
var
  Enum: TPair<string, TForm>;
  MyDict: TDictionary<string, TForm>;
begin
  MyDict := TDictionary<string, TForm>.Create;
  try
    MyDict.Add('Form1', Self);
    for Enum in MyDict do
      ShowMessage(Enum.Key);
  finally
    MyDict.Free;
  end;
```

Paste this code in the FormCreate event of any form and see for yourself.

Comment: In Delphi 2009 it does not (or not always) work, a bug is reported in QC: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=75543

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).